# Checking face visibility to a camera with dot product doesn't alway work in perspective view

Tags: python

I am writing a script to project 3d elements on a 2D plane, showing only the visible faces.

To do that I am checking that the dot product between the face normal and the vector Z of the camera is > 0.
If the camera is set to orthographic, this is always working, but when the camera is in perspective mode, there are some exceptions.
What I noticed, is that some faces that are visible in orthographic view, are hidden in perspective view due the perspective deformation.
The dot product is an operation that doesn't take in consideration if the camera is in perspective mode or orthographic since it is a mathematical operation between two vectors.

What is the best practice to overcome this issue?
I was thinking to check the normal again, once the object is projected on the 2D plane, but maybe there is a more straightforward way to do it.

The following screenshot shows the face visible in orthographic view
[image]

which is hidden in perspective view
[image]

Comment: I'd try shooting a ray from the center of the polygon, to the center of the camera, if it hits a polygon then it's facing the wrong way. This will only work with very simple meshes though

Comment: use dot product but not with cam Z: use cam position to face center instead. But that won't tell you if the face is visible: it will tell you if it is front or back facing (from the cam pov).

Comment: To calculate the dot product between the normalized vector connecting the camera center and the face center, with the face normal, does the job.
I found the solution without reading the comments but, still, thank you both.

Comment: Cool. Could you please answer your own question?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found, in case of perspective view, is to calculate the dot product between the face normal and the vector given by the line connecting the center of the camera with the center of the face I want to test.

Reason is that on orthogonal view all the rays casting from the camera are parallel to the Z axis of the camera, where on a perspective view the rays casting from the camera are not parallel.

A bit of explanatory - and not optimized - code:

```
cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
if cam.data.type == "PERSP":
    projection_type = "perspective"
else:
    projection_type = "orthographic"
for f in obj.data.polygons: #test every face of the active object
    if projection_type == "orthographic":
            face_normal = obj.matrix_world.to_quaternion() @ f.normal
            normalized_face_normal = face_normal.normalized()
            dot_product = normalized_cam_z.dot(normalized_face_normal)
    else:
            face_center = obj.matrix_world @ f.center
            camera_pos = cam.location
            face_normal = obj.matrix_world.to_quaternion() @ f.normal
            normalized_face_normal = face_normal.normalized()
            vector = camera_pos - face_center #vector given by the line between camera origin and face center
            normalized_vector = vector.normalized()
            dot_product = normalized_vector.dot(normalized_face_normal)
            
    if dot_product > 0:
            # do things
```